# Symfony Doctrine get first sorted item from OneToMany relation

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

So I have two entities:

Import:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Executions", mappedBy="import")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"startedAt" = "DESC"})
 */
private $executions;
```

and Executions:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="started_at", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
 */
private $startedAt = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';
```

One import can have many executions. And what I need is a property of lastExecution in import entity. Is it possible to select only one item from executions entity by ordering it by startedAt property?

The executions property which is also sorted by startedAt at the moment contains all the executions related to one import. And I want only one execution which has latest startedAt date.

I tried to define new property like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\StockPriceImportExecutions", mappedBy="import")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"startedAt" = "DESC"})
 */
private $lastExecution;
```

But orderBy doesn't seem to work this way. It always returns one and only execution item, which is not latest.

What could be the best way to implement this? Goal is to have a property which contains an object of latest execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another getter, that will return your last record.
The first option with sorting that you use

```
public function getLastRecord(): ?Execution
{
    return $this->executions->isEmpty() ? null : $this->executions->first();
}
```

And the second with criteria, in that case, you don't need `@ORM\OrderBy({"startedAt" = "DESC"})`

```
public function getLastRecord(): ?Execution
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->orderBy(['startedAt' => 'DESC'])
        ->setMaxResults(1);

    $result = $this->executions->matching($criteria);

    return $result->isEmpty() ? null : $result->first();
}
```

Comment: Amazing, criteria works perfectly. Yes, I used the orderBy on my getExecutions method but I wanted lastExecution property to be separated from the main one. Thank you!